# How to get the first name of a contact in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-contacts

I'm trying to get the information of my contacts using `ContactsContract` and what I need to do, is to get only the first name of the contact. I used `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME` but this get the name and the last name too, and I only want the name.

I tried using `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME` but instead of getting the name, this get a number.

I have not found an exact way to get only the first name of the contact. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shared your code, but it sounds like you're querying over table `Phone.CONTENT_URI` and trying to get a field via `StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME`.

That's not possible, as `Phone.CONTENT_URI` will only return phone rows, not StructuredName rows.

Here's code snippet to get all given-names from the Contacts DB:

```
String[] projection = new String[]{StructuredName.CONTACT_ID, StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME};
String selection = Data.MIMETYPE + "='" + StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'";

Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(Data.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, null, null);

DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(c);
c.close();
```

**UPDATE**

Here's some sample code on how to query for multiple mimetypes in a single query.
In this example I created a mapping from  to <given-name, phone> for each contact in the DB:

```
Map<Long, List<String>> contacts = new HashMap<Long, List<String>>();

String[] projection = {Data.CONTACT_ID, Data.DISPLAY_NAME, Data.MIMETYPE, StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME, Phone.NUMBER };

// select all rows of type "name" or "phone"
String selection = Data.MIMETYPE + " IN ('" + Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "', '" + StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "')";
Cursor cur = cr.query(Data.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, null, null);

while (cur != null && cur.moveToNext()) {
    long id = cur.getLong(0);
    String name = cur.getString(1);
    String mime = cur.getString(2); // type of row: phone / name

    // get the existing <Given-name, Phone> list from the Map, or create a new one
    List<String> infos;
    if (contacts.containsKey(id)) {
        infos = contacts.get(id);
    } else {
        infos = new ArrayList<String>(2);
        contacts.put(id, infos);
    }

    // add either given-name or phone to the infos list
    switch (mime) {
        case Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE: 
            infos.set(1, cur.getString(4));
            break;
        case StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE: 
            infos.set(0, cur.getString(3));
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: And using StructuredName rows its possible to get the phone number of the contact?

Comment: if you need data from multiple mimetypes (Names and Phones) you can query on Data.CONTENT_URI table, and select the specific mimetypes you need

Comment: I didn't find any sample of something similar. If it's not too much trouble, could you show me an example of how it would be done? Thank you!